# Multiple filters for same field in wave:update

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura, einstein-analytics, filters

I'm developing a Salesforce Aura component that updates an existing Wave Analytics dashboard whenever something changes within the component.

Those changes may affect same field with several values that are non excluding, like an OR filter. I'm generating this filter structure in JavaScript right now:

```js
const filter = {
  datasets: {
    [datasetName]: [
      {
        fields: ['columnName'],
        filter: { 
          operator: '>=<=',
          values: [
            [0, 2],
            [-2, 1],
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I tried this way and seems like it is applying filters with AND, but I'm not sure because the UI is not reflecting it properly.

Is there any way to set N filters to same column with OR conditions?